Phaser 3 - tilemap.createBlankLayer -> putTileAt issues when using multiple tilesets
So I am working on a small hobby project using Phaser 3 and have run into some issues working with Tile map layers.
Right now I am creating a tilemap layer and using multiple spritesheets I'm loading in. I used to have several layers I used to handle this and that worked great, however I was looking to consolidate this down to one layer since it appears that there is functionality for using multiple tilesets in one layer (see the tileset options for an array of tilesets). I've run into the issue that after setting it up and trying to place tiles from the specified tileset It is only ever pulling the sprites from the first one at the index of whatever tileset I'm trying to pull from. so if I dump all the tiles in a grid I get this:
You see the first tilesheet is being repeated even though the lengths of each are correct. So I get all 350 tiles from the first sheet, then 318 or so for the second, then 60, then 30 but all of them start pulling the original spritesheet's images.
Here's the relevant code:
initTileSets() {
    // Initialize tilemap
    this.bgTilemap = this.scene.make.tilemap({
        width: this.mapWidth,
        height: this.mapHeight,
        tileWidth: this.tileSize,
        tileHeight: this.tileSize
    });

    // Add all tilesets to the tilemap
    this.terrainTiles = this.bgTilemap.addTilesetImage('terrainTileset');
    this.terrainTiles2 = this.bgTilemap.addTilesetImage('terrainTileset2');
    this.rogueTiles = this.bgTilemap.addTilesetImage('rogueTileset');
    this.snowTiles = this.bgTilemap.addTilesetImage('snowTileset');

    //Set the length of each tileset
    let terrainTilesetLength = this.terrainTiles.total;
    let terrainTileset2Length = this.terrainTiles2.total;
    let rogueTilesetLength = this.rogueTiles.total;
    let snowTilesetLength = this.snowTiles.total;

    //Set the first gid of each tileset to the total of the previous tileset
    this.terrainTiles.firstgid = 0;
    this.terrainTiles2.firstgid = terrainTilesetLength;
    this.rogueTiles.firstgid = terrainTilesetLength + terrainTileset2Length;
    this.snowTiles.firstgid = terrainTilesetLength + terrainTileset2Length + rogueTilesetLength;

    // Store tileset information
    this.tilesetsInfo = [
        { name: 'terrainTileset', firstgid: this.terrainTiles.firstgid },
        { name: 'terrainTileset2', firstgid: this.terrainTiles2.firstgid },
        { name: 'rogueTileset', firstgid: this.rogueTiles.firstgid },
        { name: 'snowTileset', firstgid: this.snowTiles.firstgid }
    ];

    let allTilesets = [
        this.terrainTiles,
        this.terrainTiles2,
        this.rogueTiles,
        this.snowTiles
    ];

    // Create two main layers
    this.terrainLayer = this.bgTilemap.createBlankLayer('terrainLayer', allTilesets, 0, 0);

    this.detailLayer = this.bgTilemap.createBlankLayer('detailLayer', allTilesets, 0, 0);

    //log detaillayer
    console.log(this.detailLayer);

    // Optionally, you can manage all layers together if you need to apply settings to all
    this.allLayers = [
        this.terrainLayer,
        this.detailLayer
    ];
}

getTilesetForIndex(globalIndex) 
{
    for (let i = this.tilesetsInfo.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        let tileset = this.tilesetsInfo[i];
        if (globalIndex >= tileset.firstgid) 
        {
            return this.bgTilemap.getTileset(tileset.name);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

placeTile(x, y, globalIndex, layer) 
{
    let tileset = this.getTilesetForIndex(globalIndex);
    if (!tileset) 
    {
        console.error(`Tileset not found for global index: ${globalIndex}`);
        return;
    }

    //log name of tileset, first gid, and global index
    //console.log('tileset: ' + tileset.name + ' | firstgid: ' + tileset.firstgid + ' | globalIndex: ' + globalIndex);
    // Calculate the local tile index within the selected tileset
    let localIndex = globalIndex - tileset.firstgid;

    // Place the tile
    layer.putTileAt(localIndex, x, y, false, tileset.name);
}

getTotalTilesInLayer(layer) 
{
    let totalTiles = 0;
    layer.tileset.forEach(tileset => {
        totalTiles += tileset.total;
    });
    return totalTiles;
}

placeDebugTileLine()
{
    for (let i = 0; i < this.getTotalTilesInLayer(this.detailLayer); i++) 
    {

        let row = Math.floor(i/25);
        let col = i % 25;
        
        this.placeTile(col, row, i, this.detailLayer);
    }
}

One thing I have noticed is that in placeTile() the layer.putTileAt method seems to ignore the final parameter. I can put in 'invalidTileSetNameHere' and it will continue as normal in the screenshot which seems odd given the documentation on it.
Update: Using info from the response I now have this. However I get an undefined error once the map.putTileAt loop reaches i = 350 which is the first index after the first tileMap's length (terrainTilemap) has been exhausted.

initTileSets2()
{
    let map = this.scene.make.tilemap({
        key:'map',
        width: 16,
        height: 16,
        tileWidth: 16,
        tileHeight: 16
    });

    // Add all tilesets to the tilemap
    let tiles1 = map.addTilesetImage('terrainTileset'); // 350 tiles
    let tiles2 = map.addTilesetImage('terrainTileset2'); // 324 tiles
    let tiles3 = map.addTilesetImage('rogueTileset'); // 60 tiles
    let tiles4 = map.addTilesetImage('snowTileset'); // 30 tiles
    
    //Set the first gid of each tileset to the total of the previous tileset
    tiles1.firstgid = 0;
    tiles2.firstgid = tiles1.total;
    tiles3.firstgid = tiles2.firstgid + tiles2.total;
    tiles4.firstgid = tiles3.firstgid + tiles3.total;

    let allTilesets = [
        tiles1,
        tiles2,
        tiles3,
        tiles4
    ];

    let layer1 = map.createBlankLayer('layer1', allTilesets, 20, 50).setScale(0.75);
        
    let tilePerRow = 25;
    for (let i = 0; i < tiles4.firstgid; i++) {
        let col = i % tilePerRow;
        let row  = Math.floor( i / tilePerRow );

        console.log('i: ' + i + ' | col: ' + col + ' | row: ' + row);
        map.putTileAt( i, col, row )
    }

    this.map = map;
}

One other oddity I've found: if I hardcode to stop at i = 350 (length of the first tileset) and remove the updates to the firstgid for each set of tiles, I get the following render. 
This appears to be each tileset being rendered on top of the previous one starting and index 0. So the tiles are all in the map, just when I try to make them not get stacked on top of eachother/replace the previous tileset's tiles I get the scenario before.

I updated my answer with an alternative solution, probably the intended way this should be done. Just wanted to let you know there is a better way.

The last thing you commented about layer.putTileAt(), works as designed. You are calling the function on the layer, not on the map. The layer doesn't have a fifth parameter (link to documentation), and on the map function , it I would be the layer.

SideQuestion: Was there an error in the console?

But As far as I can see it it works, I just encountered a minor bug, I'm not sure if of my code or phaser, I added a comment in my code, how I "fixed it".
Small Demo, that does more ore less the same as your code:
(There seems to be a minor bug in phaser , or my code that's what the last created texture had to be bigger)
Maybe you can use this demo to help find your error.


document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: { create },
}; 

new Phaser.Game(config);
console.clear();

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'OUTPUT')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    // Creating Textures for the tilesets
    let graphics  = this.make.graphics();
    graphics.fillStyle(0xffffff);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.fillStyle(0x0);
    graphics.fillRect(10, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.generateTexture('tileset_1', 20, 10);
    
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.fillStyle(0xcdcdcd);
    graphics.fillRect(10, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.generateTexture('tileset_2', 20, 10);
    
    graphics.fillStyle(0x00ff00);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.fillStyle(0xffff00);
    graphics.fillRect(10, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.generateTexture('tileset_3', 20, 10);
    
    graphics.fillStyle(0x0000ff);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff00ff);
    graphics.fillRect(10, 0, 10, 10);
    
    // BUG (maybe): BugFixing had to make the image bigger
    graphics.generateTexture('tileset_4', 90, 10);
    
    // END -> Creating Textures for the tilesets
    initTileSets.call(this);

}

function initTileSets() {
 
   let map = this.make.tilemap({
        key:'map',
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        tileWidth: 10,
        tileHeight: 10
    });

    // Add all tilesets to the tilemap
    let tiles1 = map.addTilesetImage('tileset_1');
    let tiles2 = map.addTilesetImage('tileset_2');
    let tiles3 = map.addTilesetImage('tileset_3');
    let tiles4 = map.addTilesetImage('tileset_4');

    //Set the length of each tileset
    let tile1Length = tiles1.total;
    let tile2Length = tiles2.total;
    let tile3Length = tiles3.total;
    let tile4Length = tiles4.total;
    
    //Set the first gid of each tileset to the total of the previous tileset
    tiles1.firstgid = 0;
    tiles2.firstgid = tile1Length;
    tiles3.firstgid = tiles2.firstgid + 2;
    tiles4.firstgid = tiles3.firstgid + 2;
    
    // Store tileset information
    this.tilesetsInfo = [
        { name: 'tiles1', firstgid: tiles1.firstgid },
        { name: 'tiles2', firstgid: tiles2.firstgid },
        { name: 'tiles3', firstgid: tiles3.firstgid },
        { name: 'tiles4', firstgid: tiles4.firstgid }
    ];

    let allTilesets = [
        tiles1,
        tiles2,
        tiles3,
        tiles4
    ];

    let layer1 = map.createBlankLayer('layer1', allTilesets, 20, 50)
        .setScale(2);
        
    let tilePerRow = 3;
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        let col = i % tilePerRow;
        let row  = Math.floor( i / tilePerRow );
        map.putTileAt( i, col, row )
    }

    this.map = map;
}
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>



Update2:
I posted this issue in the phaser discourse forum, showed they an option, how to solve this issue in a different way. (also a great place to find specific phaser help)
Simply adding the gid, in the "creation" of the tileset image function addTilesetImage, instead of afterwards.
Simple remove this lines
tiles1.firstgid = 0;
tiles2.firstgid = tile1Length;
tiles3.firstgid = tiles2.firstgid + 2;
tiles4.firstgid = tiles3.firstgid + 2;

And alter addTilesetImage lines, to add the gid as 7th parameter (link to documentation).
// Add all tilesets to the tilemap
let tiles1 = map.addTilesetImage('tileset_1','tileset_1', 
    10,10,
    0,0,
    0); // <- GID
let tiles2 = map.addTilesetImage('tileset_2','tileset_2', 
    10,10,
    0,0,
    2); // <- GID
let tiles3 = map.addTilesetImage('tileset_3','tileset_3',
    10,10,
    0,0,
    4); // <- GID
let tiles4 = map.addTilesetImage('tileset_4', 'tileset_4',
    10,10,
    0,0,
    6); // <- GID

And than you wouldn't need the aforementioned workaround.

I have pretty much copied this verbatim and put an update on the bottom of my post. The logic seems to run fine until I reach an index that is > the length of the first tileSet added to the map. if I cut off at the first tileset's length it renders just fine for that one map.

As I mentioned I think this could an issue of phaser.  In my Example I'm using tilesets each length 2, but the last image has space to fit 9 images, this is the max gid that I'm using. For some reason, (the following explanation is a guess, of the bug) one image must have "so much space" as gid's used.  That's why in my example I set the firstgid with fixed values, and have a too long image. You can test this in may demo. If you replace the 90 of this line graphics.generateTexture('tileset_4', 90, 10); with the actual length 20 you would generate the same error.

Oh so interestingly I reversed the order of the tilesets being added to smallest first and largest last and only the last tileset got rendered. I think related to the second update I put on the post it's that each successive tileset is replacing the previous one's tiles at the same indexes.

Ok continuing to debug I think your workaround can be used if I can update my imported tileSetImages length manually or the map length however. I can set the firstgid on each tileset to update to the last index of the previous and as long as none of them run over the max length (the last index of the largest single tileset added) they will display properly. So I need to manually adjust the size of the largest tileset to be the sum of all tilesets.

Exactly, I just was explaining this in a comment. :) You where faster. In any case this seems to be a bug, or the documentations needs some updates, to make the innerworkings of this feature clear.

Ok so I guess now the question I have is how do I manually update the size of a given tileset to an arbitrary length? If I can update one of the tilesets to have a length of 764 (sum of all tilesets) I can then update the firstgids and be on my merry way.

Ah GOT IT! just created a dummy graphics object and set the size to the total of all previous tilesets in similar fashion to what you did.

Perfect, I wanted to say make the last image bigger, but a dummy generate texture is a better workaround.
